# User restriction on Internet Enabled Fiori Launchpad url

Tags: sap-fiori, netweaver

We are on S/4Hana 1610 On Premise System(Embedded Architecture).

Our all user's can access Fiori Launchpad url within premise but we want only particular set of user's to be able to access Fiori Launchpad url outside (Company,Plant,Country) premise once the Fiori Launchpad url is exposed to internet.

So,how to allow only particular set of user's to access Internet exposed Fiori Launchpad url?

Regards,

Sayed

Comment: Workaround would be creating a replica of lauchpad only with different user role for those specific users.

Comment: @SunilBN Please let me know if I can restrict user's from the same Published Launchpad Link.

Answer (score 0):

Are you exposing Fiori Launchpad URL to the public internet just for this particular set of users?
In this case, there might also be the possibility to keep Fiori Launchpad in your internal Intranet as it is now and provide this
particular set of users with a secure login to your internal intranet using e.g. SecurID and similar products.
You might want to discuss this with your network folks.